# Permission denied on function Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I get access denied when I run a node.js function on AWS Lambda. I am uploading a zip file which contains the index.js and the node module packets.

Have run through this twice now and still get same error as below so any help is appreciated.

```
{

"errorMessage": "EACCES: permission denied, open '/var/task/read.js'",

"errorType": "Error",

"stackTrace": [

"Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:549:18)",

"Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:393:15)"
```

Comment: Are you using any package willing to write to this path ? Does this happen when you upload it or execute it ?

Comment: It happens when I am executing it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the same problems weeks ago.

Appears that setting file permissions on .js files before zipping solves this error.

Run: `filename.js chmod -R 644` in your Terminal

Hope this saves someone else time & effort.

Answer (score 2):

AWS knows about that case. You can see the way to fix it here: https://aws.amazon.com/ru/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-deployment-package-errors/ I's not common to reach this error, really.

Probably AWS SAM or Serverless Framework will help you to be free from that hand work

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well, but with a Lambda created directly using the AWS Lambda editor. I fixed the issue by doing a new handle file.